# статическая переменная в не-статическом методе

Tags: java, static

```
public class Human { 
    static int xss;

    public void go(){
        System.out.println(xss);
    }
}
```

Не понимаю почему это скомпилируется, если `xss` это статическая переменная, а `go` это метод не-статический, разве это должно работать? Почему тогда статический метод не принимает не-статическую переменную? Или это работает потому что это не-статический метод будет вызывать объект и поэтому это будет работать, т.к статическую переменную можно тоже вызвать через объект?

Comment: из статического метода к полям класса обратиться нельзя, т.к. статика атрибут класса а не экземпляра, а наоборот можно

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ответьте как ответ на вопрос, я галку поставлю, может кому-нибудь нужно будет

Comment: @MikeMclaren я уже писал ответ, ну ладно) У Stranger хорошие ответы)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из статического метода к полям или методам экземпляра класса обратиться нельзя, т.к. статика принадлежит классу а не экземпляру, а наоборот (из метода экземпляра класса к статике) можно.

В противном случае статика была бы сама по себе от остальной программы, иначе как к ней получить доступ?

Статика инициализируется в момент загрузки класса класс-лоадером, а поля экземпляра, в момент создания самого экземпляра (`new Human()`).

---

offtopic:

Статика нормально применима для констант и методов, не зависящих от контекста вызова.

В остальных случаях она практически всегда "медвежья услуга", сначала Вам кажется что это удобно, а потом вдруг оказывается что тестами все намного сложнее покрыть или статика намертво вросла в программу и ничего с этим уже не поделать.

Comment: `полям или методам класса` - всё же "объекта" или "экземпляра", а не "класса"

Comment: @rjhdby Ваша правда, слово пропустил